# What to do in "Error 404--Not Found" situation created by weblogic URL handling?

Tags: jsp, web-applications, http-status-code-404, case-sensitive, weblogic-10.x

I have a J2EE Struts app deployed on Weblogic 10.3. When clicking on one of the link it throws "Error 404--Not Found" however the same link works fine when the app is deployed on Weblogic 8.1. I have checked there is no change in the JSP code recently and  JSP is copied correctly in the application directory. Please advise what I am missing here ?

**EDIT:** The error was resolved when changed below code

```
document.someForm.action="/somePath/someFile.jsp";  // code 1
```

to

```
document.someForm.action="/somePath/SomeFile.jsp";  //code 2
```

Note that I initcapped the jsp name as I have the jsp as Somefile.jsp. Now I don't understand why code 1 works in weblogic 8 and not Weblogic 10. What are the things should I consider when dealing with such case sensitive issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay here is the deal. It looks like Webapp URL are case insensitive in Weblogic 8 and case sensitive in Weblogic 10 by default. However good news is that we can manage this feature from Weblogic console. I toggled the below parameter to 'os' and my app started working fine without any other changes.

> Console->Domain->Security->General-> Advanced-> Web App Files Case Insensitive:

[This](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=688644) thread helped me finding out the solution.